# heroku pg:psql --app my-app fails with command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

### Environment

- Mac OSX Maverick
- Rails 3.2.11
- Ruby 1.9.2p290
- Heroku toolbelt

From my terminal:

```
$ heroku pg:psql --app my-app
---> Connecting to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN_URL (DATABASE_URL)
sh: psql: command not found
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This means that you don't have the `psql` command in your system. Try `which psql` to confirm. If you have installed postgres, then it means that its `bin` directory is not in your $PATH. If you haven't installed postgres yet, then install postgres and try again.

Answer (score 4):

Run `brew install postgres` and it should work.