# PG Bench on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

Is it possible to run pgbench on heroku?

- I see here [it's a CLI argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063095/syntax-error-when-using-pgbench) (not a postgres command)
- As of nearly 10 years ago, it wasn't a thing. But is it now? https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras/issues/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to your Heroku database using [`heroku pg:psql`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-psql-database) you [actually use a `psql` running locally on your machine to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24687985/354577) to the remote server.

Similarly, you should be able to use a local `pgbench` even though there isn't a Heroku CLI wrapper for it. Retrieve your database connection information using [`heroku config:get DATABASE_URL`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-config-get-key) or [`heroku pg:credentials`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-credentials-database), then run the command with the [common connection options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html#PGBENCH-COMMON-OPTIONS):

```
pgbench -h HOST -p 5432 -U USER DATABASE_NAME
```

Since it is a standard [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax), you can pull the hostname, username, password, and port out of Heroku's database URL like so:

```
postgres://user:password@host:port/database
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! pgbench -h HOST -p 5432 -U USER DATABASE_NAME -i worked :)